# In Sql developer ,How to remove the last 3 digit from string in all rows for one column?

Tags: sql

Colum2

```
Karim_bk 
Karim_bk 
Karim_bk
```

Want result Karim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
select top 10 Lastname, LEFT(Lastname, LEN(Lastname) - 3) as TrimmedVersion  from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. In Oracle:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column_name, 0, LENGTH(column_name) - 2) from table_name;
--SELECT SUBSTR('karim_bk', 0, LENGTH('karim_bk') - 2) from dual; --karim
```